# Why I can can not directly use my main.js file which convert form main.jsx file on browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Here is my webpack.config.js code...

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', 'babel-polyfill', './src/main.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: "./build",
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
          query:
            {
              presets:['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }
  ]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}

}
```

Here is my package.son file....

```
{
  "name": "udemy-react",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "build": "webpack",
      "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --    content-base build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

After I run npm run dev, I will have my main.js file conevert from .jsx file and everything goes well on localhost:8080.

My question is, why i cannot directly use .js file without running on web pack server?

Because I directly include main.js file in my .html and open in browser, and I got

```
Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.
```

I thought web pack already conevert everything for me , so I can directly use it.

What I should do if I want to make a production enviorment?

Comment: Probably because you specified `webpack/hot/dev-server` as entry.

Comment: @Felix Kling  Thanks a lots. I remove webpack/hot/dev-server from web pack.config.js and run webpack again to make a new main.js file and everything is working now without running server.